# What is the different between guard and invert if

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Sorry, if this is a noob question because I am new to Swift and cannot find this answer from Google.

When I first saw guard, I think of invert `if` in other programming language.

```
var optString: String?
guard optString != nil else { return }
if optString == nil { return }
```

Doesn't the second and third line produce the same result?

I can understand `if let` make the code simpler than checking `nil` and unwrapping it but what is the purpose of `guard`? From what I researched, I can only find people saying that it can reduced nested `if` which invert `if` can do the same.

> EDIT: I am asking about invert `if` **NOT** `if let`. Please read the
>   question before flagging it.

Comment: I can say that guard is the preferred method of validating inputs, as usually guards are placed at the beginning of the function, and the compiler forces you to return from the function on the else branch, this reduces the chance you forgot to return and the method body executes regardless the validity of the input data.

Comment: Also guards allow you to list the conditions for *success*, rather than the conditions for failure – making your intent clearer.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp That what a invert `if` can also do. I used invert `if` in other language to do the trick.

Comment: @Joshua This is good question. I want an answer too.

Comment: `guard` helps to write functions in a more linear manner. i.e. errors can be thrown where they occur — and not in a later else branch. http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both lines are functionally equivalent and produce the same result.

`guard` is considered better practice since the program must exit the scope in its `else` cause.

This generates an error:

`guard optString != nil else { // no return statement }`

But this does not:

`if optString == nil { // no return statement }`

Comment: Really? It introduces a new keyword just for this!? I mean if people are going to use `guard` for checking, they should know what they are doing and they will write the return statement.

Comment: In your particular case, the difference is small. When you factor in how `guard let` can unwrap an optional and keep that variable alive for the *scope of the function call*, there are more differences.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 important things about `guard` that inverted `if` (or `if let` for that matter) does not have:

- `guard` must have `else` clause that must have `return` statement or some other way of leaving the guard's parent scope (e.g. `throw` or `break`).
- Variables declared and assigned by `guard` are available in the `guard`'s parent scope.

The whole point of `guard` is that it allows you to avoid cumbersome constructs like `if let` body continuing to the end of the method because the code must only execute if some unwrapping of the optional is successful.  Basically, it's a cleaner way to implement the early exit.

So, to answer your direct question, yes `guard optString != nil else { return }` is equivalent to `if optString == nil { return }`, but that's not what `guard` was introduced for:

> Using a `guard` statement for requirements improves the readability of your code, compared to doing the same check with an `if` statement. It lets you write the code that’s typically executed without wrapping it in an `else` block, and it lets you keep the code that handles a violated requirement next to the requirement.

*Source: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525).*

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages you can almost always do things in more than 1 way.

But just as important as getting the job done, is getting the job done as good as possible.

Using a guard statement tells a future maintainer what the PURPOSE of the statement is.

So a guard statement is most definitely not the same as an inverted if statement.

See also: http://ericasadun.com/2015/12/29/migrating-ifs-to-guards-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple document:

*"A guard statement is used to transfer program control **out of a scope** if one or more conditions aren’t met."*

And we have not only 1 possibility to get out of scope with `return` key but we have 4 possibilities:

- return: stop current function/block
- break: stop current loop
- continue: stop current round and go to next round of a loop
- throw: stop current function/block and throw an error.

Your 2nd and 3rd lines have the same result cause it will stop your `scope` by the `return` command.